# Search git-annex tags / metadata and file content

Tags: git, search-engine, text-search, metadata

I have started using [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), including its [metadata/tagging](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) features to organize my personal files.

I want to be able to search the tags and other metadata that I have manually added using git annex metadata.  git annex by itself might be enough for this, though I am not sure if performance will become an issue, since I want searches to complete in under a second even when there are perhaps ten or even a hundred thousand files in a repository.

I also want to be able to quickly search the content of git-annex controlled files.  For example, the content of PDF and openoffice files.  I imagine that ideally this would use git annex metadata so as to not lose the association between git annex-controlled files and the search index, even if the working copy changes a lot because of e.g.:

- not all file content being present all the time in any given working tree (a major feature of git annex)
- [metadata driven views](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/metadata_driven_views/) causing drastically changing working tree layout over time

I imagine the index would be based on one of the lucene-based systems (in particular solr or elasticsearch), or a similar tool like xapian.  Is there any existing code that already integrates such a search system with git annex?